# Cannot join two almost identical tables with null values

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have the first table:

```
eventdatetime   id      os       orders
2020-11-18      32      ios      1
2020-11-18      (null)  android  658
2020-11-17      44      ios      49
```

And the second table:

```
installdatetime  id     os      installs
2020-11-18       32     ios     2
2020-11-18       54     android 1
2020-11-17       (null) ios     7
```

I want to join them, group by date, id and ios and get the following:

```
datetime    id     os      orders installs
2020-11-18  32     ios     1      2
2020-11-18  (null) android 658    (null)
2020-11-17  44     ios     49     (null)
2020-11-17  (null) ios     (null) 7
```

I used but it didn't work:

```
select table1.InstallDatetime as Datetime, table1.id ,table1.os, table1.orders, table2.install from table1
    
full join table2 
on 
(table1.EventDatetime=table2.InstallDatetime  or table1.EventDatetime is null and table2.InstallDatetime is null) and
(table1.id=table2.id  or table1.id is null and table2.id is null) and
(table1.os=table2.os  or table1.os is null and table2.os is null)
order by Datetime desc
```

PLease help!

Comment: Didn't work - how? Error message, or not the expected result?

Comment: OUTER JOIN don't need all `is null` conditions.

Comment: The logic does not seem consistent. Why aren't both recodrs on November 17th grouped together?

Comment: They are grouped together when I use that code but I want to have null and 44 seperately

Comment: @jarlh, not the expected result they all null values went away when I used that code

Comment: Why is the row `2020-11-18       54     android 1` not included in the results?

Comment: @forpas my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
select coalesce(eventdatetime, installdatetime) date, 
  coalesce(o.id, i.id) id, 
  coalesce(o.os, i.os) os,
  orders,
  installs
from `project.dataset.table1` o
full outer join `project.dataset.table2` i
on coalesce(o.eventdatetime, date(timestamp_seconds(0))) = coalesce(i.installdatetime, date(timestamp_seconds(0)))
and coalesce(o.id, -777) = coalesce(i.id, -777)
and coalesce(o.os, '') = coalesce(i.os, '')
```

Comment: "coalesce(o.id,) is highlighted in red
No matching signature for function COALESCE for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: COALESCE([ANY, ...]) at [19:1]

Comment: it is not clear what exactly data types of your columns - so change `-777` to `''` - that simple. try and let me know if still "problems" :o)